# Python werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request request.files

Tags: python, flask

The Python application is trying to get 3 files from the user and process them. When doing this I get an error:
If there is only one field for files, then everything works. If I add another field, I get an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "/application/project/certificate-home/cert.py", line 63, in convert
file_key = request.files['file_key']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures/structures.py", line 192, in __getitem__
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file_key'
```

Python code

```
@app.route('/convert', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def convert():
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/application/project/certificate-home/uploads'
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        crt_in = request.form['in']
        crt_out = request.form['out']

        file = request.files['file_cert']
        file.save(file.filename)
        generate_name = UPLOAD_FOLDER+'/'+file.filename


        file_key = request.files['file_key']
        file_key.save(file_key.filename)
        generate_key_name = UPLOAD_FOLDER+'/'+file.filename

        file_chain = request.files['file_chain']
        file_chain.save(file_chain.filename)
        generate_chain_name = UPLOAD_FOLDER+'/'+file_key.filename
```

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="file_cert" type="file" name="file_cert" value="file_cert">
<input class="form-control" id="file_key" type="file" name="file_key" value="file_key">
<input class="form-control" id="file_chain" type="file" name="file_chain" value="file_chain">
```

As far as I understand, the error occurs when an empty field arrives instead of a file.
Any ideas what could be wrong?